# Python telnetlib getting strange escape characters

Tags: python, encoding, telnetlib

I'm using telnetlib to connect to device and send some commands over
Everything seems to work fine, but when I try to read response after sending command, command text gets back in wierd format with lot of escape characters

To demonstrate
I connect to device

```py
self.terminal = telnetlib.Telnet(device, port)
```

I send command (and it gets executed as expected)

```
self.terminal.write(b'config\r\n')
```

And then read response

```
telnetResponse = self.terminal.read_until(b'(Config)#', self.telnetTimeout)
```

Response I get is my command in some wierd encoding with lot of escape characters and then the rest of response that is normal

> b'\x1b7c\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7o\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7n\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7f\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7i\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7g\x1b8\x1b[1C\n\rmydevice(Config)#'

Everything I get back from read_until is perfectly normal with no escape characters and strange encoding except commands I sent, even when I send command that returns some kind of response, everything is readable but my command
Tried encoding and decoding result in any way I could think of, but encoding it just produces different kind of junk

> mydevice#7c8[1C7o8[1C7n8[1C7f8[1C7i8[1C7g8[1C

I'm using Python 3.11.5 on Ubuntu in WSL

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
> Release:        22.04
> Codename:       jammy

Even tried with older versions of pyhton (3.9) but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of better idea I ended up doing my initial idea, regexing all escape characters from response

```py
ansi_regex = b'\x1b(' \
             b'(\[\??\d+[hl])|' \
             b'([=<>a-kzNM78])|' \
             b'([\(\)][a-b0-2])|' \
             b'(\[\d{0,2}[ma-dgkjqi])|' \
             b'(\[\d+;\d+[hfy]?)|' \
             b'(\[;?[hf])|' \
             b'(#[3-68])|' \
             b'([01356]n)|' \
             b'(O[mlnp-z]?)|' \
             b'(/Z)|' \
             b'(\d+)|' \
             b'(\[\?\d;\d0c)|' \
             b'(\d;\dR))'
ansi_escape = re.compile(ansi_regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
communication = ansi_escape.sub(b'', communication)
```

It produces output as expected, at least in examples I have for now

Answer (score 0):

This can happen becauseof the way the remote device interprets and echoes back the command. Since you know the command you sent, you can strip it from the response string. For example:

```py
command = b'config\r\n'
telnetResponse = self.terminal.read_until(b'(Config)#', self.telnetTimeout)

# Remove echoed command from response
telnetResponse = telnetResponse[len(command):]
```

After removing the echoed command using the modified code, your `telnetResponse` variable result in:

```
Setting up configuration...
Configuration complete.
(Config)#
```

Referring to your comment:

```py
import re

# Initialize a list to store executed commands
executed_commands = []

# Function to send a command and capture the response
def send_command(command):
    self.terminal.write(command)
    executed_commands.append(command.decode('utf-8'))  # Store the executed command as a string

# Example usage:
send_command(b'config\r\n')
telnetResponse = self.terminal.read_until(b'(Config)#', self.telnetTimeout)

# Convert the response to a string
response_text = telnetResponse.decode('utf-8')

# Use regular expressions to remove the echoed command, taking into account any format
for cmd in executed_commands:
    response_text = re.sub(rf'^.*?{re.escape(cmd.decode("utf-8"))}', '', response_text, flags=re.DOTALL)

# Print the executed command and cleaned response
print(f"Executed command: {executed_commands[-1]}")
print(f"Cleaned Response: {response_text.strip()}")
```

i added re.sub function to remove the echoed command from the response text, taking into account any control characters that might be present.
I hope this helps

Comment: Problem is in my response length of command is not same as in my code, in example above command i send is `config\r\n` and what i get from output for that is all that in quote block, after doing telnetResponse = telnetResponse[len(command):] I still get lot of junk:   
`Original response:
b'\x1b7c\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7o\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7n\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7f\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7i\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7g\x1b8\x1b[1C\n\rmydevice(Config)#'`  
`New response:
b'C\x1b7o\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7n\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7f\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7i\x1b8\x1b[1C\x1b7g\x1b8\x1b[1C\n\rmydevice(Config)#'`
Also I would like to see commands

Comment: Edited my answer @BeRightBack

Comment: That still doesn't work in my case, I can add commands to log like that and that is ok, but response_text in exact example after re.sub turns out to be `7c8[1C7o8[1C7n8[1C7f8[1C7i8[1C7g8[1C` Cause command I send is `config\r\n` and in decoded response that is shown as `7c8[1C7o8[1C7n8[1C7f8[1C7i8[1C7g8[1C`, so there is no "config" for sub method to remove

Comment: Hm, I see. i suggest using regEx to sort these echoes out, edited answer again, I can’t test it myself rn but this could work

Comment: Yeah, it's not easy to solve this when you don't have same problem, so thank you for trying. But this still doesn't work, `cmd.decode("utf-8")` doesn't produce same text as I get it from terminal, so sub method still doesn't replace anything. Maybe I could try to build custom regex adding ]1C and other stuff to replace, but I'm not even sure is that something I will always get depending on command and characters in it, so it doesn't seem like good solution

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, i can try it later today so i can provide better help :)